# XGBoost Mean Average Precision eval_metric for Classification

Tags: optimization, model-evaluation, hyperparameter, boosting, average-precision

I am testing XGBoostClassifier for a binary classification problem.  I have tried a few base models, done some simple parameter tuning, and performed feature selection using sklearn's `RFE`.  The goal of this classification problem is to optimize for precision at all possible thresholds and rank test data by the likelihood of being in the positive class.  I have been setting the scoring parameter to `scoring='average_precision'` when cross validating on my training set using sklearn's `cross_val_score`.

I am now ready to perform more extensive hyperparameter tuning and have looked at the XGBoost documentation and am wondering what `eval_metric` I should be using to optimize my model.  I am not seeing 'average_precision' or even 'precision' as an evaluation metric but have found 'map' (mean average precision) which the documentation explicitly states is used for ranking. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#

Obviously this is not the same metric I had been using previously but is this my best option?  Otherwise should I consider using a different evaluation metric such as logloss?  Any feedback would be appreciated.